# Get a list of non-set value lang string in blade file of Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have applied multiple languages in my project Laravel 5.6. The lang string (For example: `{{ __('messages.welcome') }}`) is used to show a translation by a case in blade file.

However, after design a several of pages, I do not know how many created lang strings are not set a value in a lang file.

**My question:** is there any way to check or show a lang string which is created in blade but is not set a value in lang file?

Comment: I am assuming you don't want to goto all the files and manually add @lang(variable) or __(variable) to your blade files. I have the same issue, the project has become huge and going to all the pages and adding the translatable variables is a huge task. Did you find a way to to that? (The package mentioned in the accepted answer only scans for the translatable variables right? Or does it automatically detects strings and converts it into variables?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install a package like: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

This will expose a UI and some artisan commands which will allow you to check for untranslated strings per namespace/language and edit them.

This package does however require an additional table which will hold the translation.

You can use the artisan commands:

```
php artisan translations:import
```

To import translations from you translation files into the db table

```
php artisan translations:find
```

To scan through your blade files and find untranslated strings

```
php artisan translations:export
```

To export changes made in the package UI and write back to the translation files, after which you can simply commit your changes.